# Can you use a decorator to add an additional parameter to the inner function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Is there a (good) method for using a decorator to add another parameter to the decorated (inner) function. I think I've found a method that will do some of it, but seems hacky and has at least one problem.

My scenario (which I could likely solve in a better way, but just wondering here), is for a daily data script I run where I want some functions to have a parameter for 'phase' and this would do the same thing for each phase. For example,

```py
def func(arg1,arg2,phase):
    # do some stuff specific to the function
    if phase == 1:
        pass
    elif phase == 2:
        # do something else, the same something in multiple different functions
    else:
        raise ValueError('phase needs to be 1 or 2')
```

I found myself writing the exact same thing in 4 different functions after the 'do some stuff'. So I thought that maybe I could use a decorator to basically add everything from the `if phase == 1` to the end and just have the `do stuff` inside each func that is unique to it.

In some testing, I found a way to accomplish this, but I'm not sure if it is the best way, and also the docstrings get all messed up... Here's what I have so far:

```py
import functools


def add_phase(func):
    add_to_doc = """\nhere is the add_phase docstring"""
    func.__doc__ += add_to_doc

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(param, phase):
        """here is the wrapper docstring"""
        if phase == 1:
            print("got to this line")
        elif phase == 2:
            return func(param)
        else:
            raise ValueError
    return wrapper

@add_phase
def func(param):
    "here is the reg1 docstring"
    st = f"statement {param}"
    print(st)

func("param", phase=2)
```

With these, I am able to call `func` with both parameters and it works. However, when I call `help` on it it shows that it tells that it just takes `param` and not `phase`.

I also want to add the information to the docstring for any function that the decorator is on saying what `phase` does. I was able to accomplish that by putting the `add_to_doc...` two lines in the decorator `add_phase` before we get to the wrapper. That results in `help(func)` giving the docstring with its original plus the addition. But it still just shows the one param. Also, when I hover over `func` in VSCode, the help-text there just gives the func docstring, not with the decorator docstring info added.

So, is there some already-developed method to do this that I'm missing? Is this method likely going to break? Is there a way to update what shows in the params in the docstring?

Last, yes, I could probably more easily accomplish this specific task by testing `phase` outside the functions and having them all in an if block, but that would be boring.

Comment: this doesnt quite pass the smell test for me ... i dont understand why you would want to do this? but it definitely seems like a decorator is probably not the right approach (it obscures whats happening and will likely end up leading to weird hard to debug issues) ... that said without knowing more theres no way i can say that definitively, and in anycase im sure you can make it work if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just dont functools.wrap the function...

```
def add_phase(func):
    def wrapper(param, phase):
        if phase == 1:
            print("got to this line")
        elif phase == 2:
            return func(param)
        else:
            raise ValueError
    wrapper.__doc__ = f"Wraps: {func.__name__} and injects an arg\n{func.__doc__}"
    return wrapper
```

then you can see it

```
>>> help(func)
Help on function wrapper in module __main__:

wrapper(param, phase)
    Wraps: func and injects an arg
    here is the reg1 docstring
```

but really this seems like it will be fairly painful and a bad idea...

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I mostly was wondering "is this a situation for a decorator?" And it sounds like the answer is "no". That helps. Tyty